# KeyNotFoundException vs returning null in Kotlin

Tags: design-patterns, kotlin, null

I'm trying to decide on a function in a Kotlin interface that reads a value from configuration based on a give key. The two options would be

```
/**
 * Reads a configuration value for the specified key.
 * @param key The key to the configuration value to retrieve
 * @return The configuration value if the key is present, exception otherwise
 */
fun readValue(key: String): String
```

```
/**
 * Reads a configuration value for the specified key.
 * @param key The key to the configuration value to retrieve
 * @return The configuration value if the key is present, null otherwise
 */
fun readValue(key: String): String?
```

Where, as show, the main difference is raising an exception or returning null value.

Given my background in Java and C# it feel natural to me to write the second form and require the caller to check for null before accesing the value, however I'm not sure whether that applies to Kotlin or there's a general preference to avoid returning null values whenever possible.

Comment: This question is pretty opinion-based. Even in languages without exceptions, some functions are still controversial as to whether they should return null or to panic.

Comment: Yes it is a bit opinion-based, but (again imo) the base for the second opinion (exception/panic) has shrunken in kotlin. I would love to have some examples for the first option (with exception) that will provide some benefit and takes the special language features of kotlin into consideration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Kotlin, you have decent null handling. So opposed to java, no need to avoid null, you can embrace it.

So i would choose your second option and let the consumer of your Api decide themself.

They can use the Elvis Operator:

```
val value = readValue("key") ?: "";
val value2 = readValue("key2") ?: throw IllegalArgumentException();
```

Or add the exact extension method they want to use.

```
fun Repository.readOrEmpty(key:String):String {
    return this.readValue(key)?:""
}
fun Repository.readOrElse(key:String, defaultValue:String):String {
    return this.readValue(key)?:defaultValue
}
fun Repository.readOrThrow(key:String):String {
    return this.readValue(key)?:throw IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Both usages would be awkward/impossible if you go for your first option.

Comment: Alternatively, go functional and return an Option